# GPA for PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

I am applying for PhD programs in mathematics and statistics for the next fall semester, and I am really concerned about my GPA for this fall semester.

My GPA is solid before this semester, and I have done quite well in all upper-division undergrad classes and 1 graduate class (complex analysis).

As everything was going really well, I decided to take two graduate classes (algebra and real analysis) this fall semester, along with 4 other classes. It didn't go well for me. I got B's for both of the graduate classes (A for everything else).

There were not really any special circumstances. It was me getting overwhelmed by the sheer number of tasks from classes and grad-school application and a bit of complacency from doing well in the beginning of the semester.

At this point, I don't believe there is much I can do, but I still would like to know how much damage these two B's will do to my application(math programs and statistics programs separately). (Maybe rate it from a scale of 0 to 10, with 0 being "no effect" and 10 being "this will ruin my application and deny my entrance to anywhere".)

Answer (score 4):

Two Bs in significantly harder, graduate level classes will not harm your chances of admission much if at all. Your GPA will only take a very slight dip from them (assuming your other marks are high) and, really, you did fine for your level. Remember that you are a whole package, not a just GPA. Write a good statement of purpose, work on doing well on the GREs if you are talking about the US, and do some volunteer research assistance to pad your CV. You're fine!

Comment: +1 for "whole package". You are more than your GPA.